# JS - Как записать данные в существующий файл csv?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

***Пишу расширение для хрома:***

при нажатии на кнопку парсится инфа с сайта и скачивается в csv файл, все работает ***почти*** как надо, столкнулся с проблемой при ***многократном парсинге скачивается много файлов***, как этого избежать?

***Вопрос:***

1. Как при нажатии на кнопку, дописать информацию в csv файл?
2. Если файла не существует, то при первом скачивание он создастся, а каждое последующие скачивание нужно в него записать информацию, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: на вашем сервере или на компютере пользователя? если второе... ну вы захотели конечно

Comment: Формировать файл на сервере и предлагать загрузить. Иначе никак.

Comment: @Oleksandr, вопрос обновил посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Никак. Доступ к файловой системе у расширений отстуствует. Из решений - использование debounce при парсинге или формирование файла самим расширением на основании ответа сервера.